# Как в Битрикс, в товарах, где есть торговые предложения, при смене цвета, в url отображать ссылку (символьный код) а не get параметр?

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, битрикс24

Как в Битрикс, в товарах, где есть торговые предложения, при смене цвета, в url отображать ссылку (символьный код) а не get параметр?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы вместо этого get параметра была ссылка **/belaya-emal-ma-15-30-kg**

Эта ссылка будет браться из торгового предложения, это символьный код.

Куда мне капать, что смотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. в параметр SEF_URL_TEMPLATES каталога добавляем после element

```
"element" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
"offer" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/#OFFER_CODE#/",
```

2. В шаблоне каталога создаем файл offer.php

```
<? if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

//$arResult['VARIABLES']['OFFER_CODE']

include 'element.php';
```

3. в element.php передаем в параметры catalog.element `$arResult['VARIABLES']['OFFER_CODE']` по аналогии с `$arResult['VARIABLES']['ELEMENT_CODE']`
4. в шаблоне catalog.element (или в result_modifier.php) проверяем `$arParams['OFFER_CODE']`. Если там не пусто, ищем в массиве `$arResult['OFFERS']` нужный оффер, берем индекс и передаем в `$arResult['OFFERS_SELECTED']`
5. Меняем настройки чпу в инфоблоке торговых предложений на `#PRODUCT_URL#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/`
6. Дорабатываем catalog.element script.js так, чтобы он перезаписывал url c помощью History API или открывал новую страницу по клику на цвет.